# Kubernetes CronJob Stops Scheduling Jobs

Tags: kubernetes

Not sure what I am doing wrong, but I am experiencing an issue where CronJobs stop scheduling new Jobs. It *seems* like this happens only after a couple of failures to launch a new Job. In my specific case, Jobs were not able to start due an inability to pull the container image.

I'm not really finding any settings that would lead to this, but I'm no expert on Kubernetes CronJobs. Configuration below:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: cron-deal-report
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Tiller
    app.kubernetes.io/name: cron
    helm.sh/chart: cron-0.1.0
  name: cron-deal-report
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - args:
            - -c
            - npm run script
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            env:
            image: <redacted>
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            name: cron
            resources: {}
            securityContext:
              runAsUser: 1000
            terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
            terminationMessagePolicy: File
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          restartPolicy: Never
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          securityContext: {}
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  schedule: 0/15 * * * *
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  suspend: false
status: {}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### How kubernetes jobs handle failures

As per [Jobs - Run to Completion - Handling Pod and Container Failures](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#handling-pod-and-container-failures):

> An entire Pod can <s>also</s> fail, for a number of reasons, such as when the
>   pod is kicked off the node (node is upgraded, rebooted, deleted,
>   etc.), **or if a container of the Pod fails and the
>   `.spec.template.spec.restartPolicy = "Never"`**. When a Pod fails, then
>   the Job controller starts a new Pod.

You are using `restartPolicy: Never` for your `jobTemplate`, so, see the next quote on [Pod backoff failure policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#pod-backoff-failure-policy):

> There are situations where you want to fail a Job after some amount of
>   retries due to a logical error in configuration etc. To do so, set
>   `.spec.backoffLimit` to specify the number of retries before considering
>   a Job as failed. **The back-off limit is set by default to 6**. The back-off count is reset if no new failed Pods appear before the Job’s next status check.

The `.spec.backoffLimit` is not defined in your `jobTemplate`, so it's using the default (`6`).

Following, as per [Job Termination and Cleanup](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#job-termination-and-cleanup):

> By default, a Job will run uninterrupted unless a Pod fails, at which
>   point the Job defers to the `.spec.backoffLimit` described above. Another way to terminate a Job is by setting an active deadline. Do this by setting the `.spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` field of the Job to a number of seconds.

That's your case: **If your containers fail to pull the image six consecutive times, your Job will be considered as failed.**

---

### Cronjobs

As per [Cron Job Limitations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#cron-job-limitations):

> A cron job creates a job object about once per execution time of its schedule [...]. The Cronjob is
>   only responsible for creating Jobs that match its schedule, and the
>   Job in turn is responsible for the management of the Pods it
>   represents.

This means that all pod/container failures should be handled by the Job Controller (i.e., adjusting the `jobTemplate`).

**"Retrying" a Job:**

You do not need to recreate a Cronjob in case its Job of fails. You only need to wait for the next schedule.

If you want to run a new Job before the next schedule, you can use the Cronjob template to create a Job manually with:

```
kubectl create job --from=cronjob/my-cronjob-name my-manually-job-name
```

---

### What you should do:

If your containers are unable to download the images constantly, you have the following options:

- Explicit set and tune `backoffLimit` to a higher value.
- Use `restartPolicy: OnFailure` for your containers, so the Pod will stay on the node, and only the container will be re-run.
- *Consider using [`imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images). If you are not retagging your images, there is no need to force a re-pull for every job start.*

Comment: The only question that remains for me is this all applies to Jobs, not CronJobs. I guess there's some implicit rule here which says a CronJob will not spawn further Jobs after one fails (and stays failed). I had to resort to removing & re-installing the CronJob. I'd half expect the "Suspend" flag on CronJob to flip to true when this happens.

Comment: A [cron job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#cron-job-limitations) creates a job object about **once** per execution time of its schedule. The Cronjob is only responsible for creating Jobs that match its schedule, and the Job, in turn, is responsible for the management of the Pods it represents, including the failure handling.

Comment: @the0ther I forgot to mention that you do not need to "removing & re-installing the CronJob". You can create a Job manually from the Cronjob template with: `kubectl create job --from=cronjob/my-cronjob-name my-manually-job-name` (I edited the answer to add this info too).

Answer (score 10):

Just to expand on [Eduardo Baitello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7641078/eduardo-baitello)'s answer I would also like to mention 2 more caveats:

1. Eduardo mentioned [Cronjob Limitations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#cron-job-limitations), but didn't expand on the `Too many missed start time (> 100)` issue. For this I've found that the only solution is to delete the cronjob and recreate it. You can patch the cronjob to decrease its frequency which tricks the scheduler to run it again. Then you can re-patch it back to how it was but this is trickier. The `kubectl describe cronjob CRONJOB_NAME` should list this as one of its events if this has been affected, and it usually affects cronjobs which have a high frequency.
2. If you have a lot of `Cronjobs`/`Jobs` then you could be experiencing this bug ([#77465](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/77465)) which has been fixed in `1.14.7`. This occurs if you have more than `500` Jobs within the entire cluster. This one is harder to find, but you can query the `kube-scheduler` logs for `expected type *batchv1.JobList, got type *internalversion.List`.

You can print the logs for `kube-scheduler` using the following command:

```
kubectl -n kube-system logs -l component=kube-scheduler --tail 100
```